# Windows 7 How to configure aero snap

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to configure the new windows 7 feature "aero snap" ? 
I'm used to "[Grid Move](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html)" which is great with a lot of possible configuration, and I would like to use aero snap the same way.

Comment: I haven't seen any way of doing so, there only seems to be the option to "Turn off automatic window arangement" and I haven't seen any APIs explosed for Areo Snap that would allow functionality of GridMove to be added to Windows 7. Does GridMove work under Windows 7 RC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any configuration available.